# How To Use Hammer Without Inner Elements Generating Events

Tags: hammer.js

When I use hammer.js to recognize gestures for an element, I expect that gestures will be recognized only for that element and not from elements inside it. In this jsfiddle example I have set up a horizontal pan for the outer, red element. But when I drag inside the inner, blue element, pan gestures are still recognized. I need just the outer element to recognize the gesture. Is there a way to code this?

https://jsfiddle.net/axvmsa9k/3/

```
<div id="red" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:red;">
    <div id="blue" style="width:100px;height:100px;background:blue;"></div>
</div>
<h1>Click and drag in red or blue element to see events happen.</h1>
<h1 id="textout">pan event count = 0</h1>
var red_el = document.getElementById("red");
// create Hammer manager to recognize horizontal pan for the red element
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(red_el, {
    preventDefault: true,
    recognizers: [
        [Hammer.Pan, {
            direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL
        }]
    ]
});

// set manager to call handlePan
mc.on('pan', handlePan);

// update the HTML to show that pan events happen when 
var eventCounter = 0;
function handlePan(ev) {
    var output_el = document.getElementById("textout");
    eventCounter++;
    output_el.innerHTML = "pan event count = "+eventCounter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using stopPropogation() to inner elements that handle mousedown events and by using the CSS pointer-events:none property for other inner elements.